# How c++ select member functions with same names?

Tags: c++, c++17

I know we can't take address of non-static member function.
If we have a non-static member function name `f` but also a static member function named `f`.
g++ knows `f` in `&c.f` is the static one, but clang does not.
Should c++ compiler needs to knows that?

g++ :7.4.0 
clang++:10.0.0

```
struct C {
  static void f(int) {}
  void f() {}
};

int main() {
  C c;
  void (*p)(int) = &c.f;
}
```

Comment: `void (*p)(int) = &C::f` would directly access the static one only. Are you just asking if this is a bug in the clang compiler?

Comment: You actually can take the address of a non-static member function: `void (C::*p)() = &C::f;`

Comment: We can have pointers to class non-static members. Read this https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/pointer-to-members.php

Comment: I know this syntax, but I just wonder why clang++ don't know `f` in `&c.f` is the static one? Is C++ spec has a rule about it?

Comment: @eddiekuo: Neither compiler knows what `&c.f` refers to. It is only when you take that expression and attempt to convert it to a function pointer that the compiler understands what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing with which compiler is, neither is capable and knows as said by @Nicol Bolas,
only static function member is possible to be referenced ie. has an alias

so nice to click: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/